# What is _.defer and _.throttle in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have seen something like

```
_.defer(function(){
    $elem.attr("src", $elem.data("delayed-src"));
});

// what is "_.defer (function)"?
```

and

```
$(window).on("scroll.load-media", _.throttle(function() {
    maybeLoadMedia(600);
}, 100));

// what is "_.throttle (function)"?
```

Is it in JavaScript by default? or do I have to add underscore.js plug-in?
http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/

Since I don't want to use an additional js except jQuery, how these functions can be replaced by pure javascript (or jquery) code? (I am implementing delayed-loading js. See http://blog.pamelafox.org/2014/01/improving-front-page-performance.html .)

Or is underscore.js just useful??? Should I use it?

Comment: Underscore.js is only 5 kb. It's far simpler to just include it instead of trying to replicate its behavior.

Comment: As for what those functions do, you just posted a link to Underscore's documentation. Read it.

Comment: @Juhana These functions are not directly documented on the website. Anyway @kipid, you'll find information in the annotated file http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html. I didn't read the whole function definition, but they don't seen trivial so as @Juhana said you'd better include `underscore.js`.

Comment: I just want to make it sure that _. is not default javascript because code in the link doesn't mention underscore.js.

Comment: @Holt What do you mean by "directly documented"? There's http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#defer and there's http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#throttle.

Comment: @Holt Thanks anyway. I think it is not pure javascript.

Comment: @Juhana Thanks. I just wondered if underscore.js is useful and used frequently in many sites.

Comment: @Juhana I'm just blind...!, @ kipid Yes it is, and even if it wasn't, nothing prevent you to use it on your website.

Comment: @Holt If it is not updated later or dead, it will not be good ^^. As I think _.defer and _.throttle have exceptionally excellent functionality, I will choose not to use them (maybe). (After I study them.)

Comment: Who cares if it's not updated later or "dies"? The script is not magically removed from your site in either case.

Comment: @Juhana As I am using small tiny part of underscore.js, I just don't want to use it adding an additional 5kb loading to visitors.

Comment: 5kb is vanishingly small. See that logo next to your name? That alone is more than 6 times larger.

Comment: @AD7six This was the first question I asked in stackoverflow. Sorry for the funny writings.

Comment: @kipid questions [have public history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23907006/revisions) - it's better ([much](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255685/761202), [much](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post) better) to write your question to always be coherent to _new_ readers. Anyone who want's to see what changed can see it was edited.

Comment: @AD7six Okay. I revised it, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Anzeo 'RM (Read Manual) theorem' will be a better word. Since I didn't know 'RTFM', I found it in the internet. TF was 'the fxxxxx'. :( And please add some explaination for an abbreviation if possible or not bothering you.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know, the `_` variable is set by [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and not provided by the JavaScript runtime itself.

Underscore.js is extremely popular, it's the number one in the "most depended upon" in the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.org/). Wappalyzer also [lists a lot very well known sites using it](https://wappalyzer.com/applications/underscorejs). There are even compatible clones like [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/), you can be sure that it will be around for a long time.

Answer (score -1):

**defer**                                                                     _.defer(function, *arguments)
Defers invoking the function until the current call stack has cleared, similar to using setTimeout with a delay of 0. Useful for performing expensive computations or HTML rendering in chunks without blocking the UI thread from updating. If you pass the optional arguments, they will be forwarded on to the function when it is invoked.

_.defer(function(){ alert('deferred'); });
// Returns from the function before the alert runs.

**throttle**                                                                _.throttle(function, wait, [options])
Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.

By default, throttle will execute the function as soon as you call it for the first time, and, if you call it again any number of times during the wait period, as soon as that period is over. If you'd like to disable the leading-edge call, pass {leading: false}, and if you'd like to disable the execution on the trailing-edge, pass
{trailing: false}.

var throttled = _.throttle(updatePosition, 100);
$(window).scroll(throttled);

Comment: Please state that you are citing some documentation, preferably even link it; and use appropriate formatting.